# How to show custom fields on Ad listing within category

Tags: php, css, osclass

I have added custom fields from Admin panel and it is show on Ad's detail page, but I want to show on Listing Pages as well, can you tell me in with file/s I need to code, PHP file, CSS, or class file.
and I dont know PHP coding, but know .Net.
thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have added a custom field Drop down to post add 'Select Discount', where user can select discount, now this discount posts on Ad's detail page, now I wand this Discount on Listing page as well, like discount shows on a website 'dealsandyou' http://www.dealsandyou.com/location/jaipur--rajasthan--india?categoryId=32&list-mode=1&browse_by=popularity&latitude=26.9124336&longitude=75.78727090000007

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, the Listing pages is the search page (where the list of items is displayed).

In order to do that you'll have to look for `search` or `after_search` hooks in `oc-includes/osclass/controller/Search.php`.

You'll need to have a DAO object too, [this tutorial should get you started](https://wearemadhouse.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/how-to-develop-osclass-plugins/).

```
osc_add_hook('after_search', function() {
    if (osc_is_search_page()) {
        osc_reset_items();
        while(osc_has_items()) {
            $detail = // Get your discount info for osc_item_id()
            if(isset($detail['fk_i_item_id'])) {
                $result[osc_item_id()] = $detail;
            }
        }
        View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView("your_plugin_name", $result);
        osc_reset_items();
    }
});
```

Then, in your theme search.php file, you can retrieve your discount info with something like this:

```
$discounts = __get("your_plugin_name");
while(osc_has_items()) {
    $discount = $discounts[osc_item_id()];
}
```